# Fetching a data from Row where value = booked; in Encrypted Sql Database using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to retrieve data from a row where value is booked and the database is encrypted.

Following is the full query:

```
$stmt = prepared_query($mysqli,
            "Select a.id as appointmentid,a.reason as reason, a.slotid,
            patientid, slottime as appointmenttime, slotdate as appointmentdate,
            Name as patientname, Email as patientemail, Photo as patientphoto,
            Phone as patientphone,Address as patientaddress, Description as patientdescription,
            Qualifications as patientqualifications, Gender , status
            from Appointments as a
            inner join DoctorSlots as ds on a.slotid=ds.slotId
            inner join Users as u on u.id=a.patientid
            where a.doctorId= ?;", [$id]);
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

and I trying to retrieve where status = value;

```
<td class="text-left">
  <?php echo decrypt($row["status"]); ?>
</td>
```

Right now its fetching the all the data from row called status where as i am trying to retrieve `where status == 1` ;

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you've said that you want to filter result only where `status == 1`, it translated to the following SQL query (modified your `WHERE` statement):

```
WHERE a.doctorId = ? AND status = '1'
```

and the whole prepared statement would be:

```
$stmt = prepared_query($mysqli,
        "Select a.id as appointmentid,a.reason as reason, a.slotid,
        patientid, slottime as appointmenttime, slotdate as appointmentdate,
        Name as patientname, Email as patientemail, Photo as patientphoto,
        Phone as patientphone,Address as patientaddress, Description as patientdescription,
        Qualifications as patientqualifications, Gender , status
        from Appointments as a
        inner join DoctorSlots as ds on a.slotid=ds.slotId
        inner join Users as u on u.id=a.patientid
        where a.doctorId= ? AND a.status = ?;", [$id], '1');
```